# displaying table in html using php and ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

I'm new to AJAX and I have to display html table from PHP.
When I pressed the generate button it should display the table below.
This is my code in HTML file:

```
function showHint()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    //what codes to put here when in terms of button.
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","list.php", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <button onClick="showHint()">Generate</button>
</body>
```

in the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()` part, What should be the statement?

this is my PHP file:

```
<?php
$a[]="James Burb";
$a[]="Melvin Chapman";
$a[]="Eric Chan";
$a[]="Aira Gomez";
echo "<table border=1>";
for($i=0; $i<count($a); $i++)
{

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>" .$hint=$a[$i]. "</td>";
echo "</tr>";

}
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `xmlhttp.responseText` to display your table in some div as follows:

```
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
}
```

it will place the table returned by `list.php` in div.